# JS: Object assign & Object.create together output looks the same as Object.create

Tags: javascript

```
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.saySomething = function() {
     return 'say Something!';
}

let john = new Person('john');

//john {name: 'john', saySomething: function}

newObj = Object.assign(Object.create(john))
```

newObj is an empty `{}` with the `john` properties as a prototype.  How does that differ from just doing `newObj = Object.create(john);` ?

Comment: Calling `Object.assign` with just one argument is indeed a useless call.

Answer (score 1):

`Object.assign` is only useful when you provide more than one argument to it. It always returns the first argument it gets, which will be mutated by the other arguments. If you just provide one argument, there is no mutation happening, and so it is a no-operation really<sup>*</sup>.

`Object.assign` is sometimes called to populate a *new* object, created on-the-fly with `{}`, and then you see that this object is not a `Person` object:

```js
function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.saySomething = function() {
     return 'say Something!';
}

let john = new Person('john');

//john {name: 'john', saySomething: function}

let created = Object.create(john);
let newObj = Object.assign({}, created);
console.log(created instanceof Person); // true
console.log(newObj instanceof Person); // false
```

---

<sub>* There is a border case where `Object.assign` still makes a difference when called with just one argument: that is when you pass it a *primitive* value. In that case it will act like the `Object` function, wrapping the primitive into an object.</sub>

Comment: Did this answer your question? Could you leave some feed-back?